# JMockit @Mocked object throws NPE

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5, jmockit

I'm trying to mock OutputStream to throw an Exception while writing, but mocked object is not initialized, and that's why I got NPE.
The piece of code:

```
@Mocked
OutputStreamWriter writer;

@Test
void testWriteFailureWithoutRetries() throws IOException {
    new Expectations() {{
       writer.write(anyString);
       result = new IOException();
    }};
    ...
}
```

In Expectations block, the writer object is null. I use jMockit 1.44, jUnit 5.4.2

UPD: problem was solved by rolling jUnit version back to 5.3.2, but probably there is a better solution?